# how to access phone number from django phonenumber_field.modelfields.PhoneNumberField?

Tags: django

I have PhoneNumberField in my django model.
How to retrieve the actual phone number from the field object.

```
class MyUser(models.Model):
    mobile = PhoneNumberField(
        verbose_name="Phone Number", blank=True, null=True, unique=True
    )

...
```

Update 1:
settings.py

```
PHONENUMBER_DB_FORMAT = 'INTERNATIONAL'
PHONENUMBER_DEFAULT_REGION = "IN"
```

I have already tried below.

```
print(mobile.as_international)
AttributeError: 'PhoneNumberField' object has no attribute 'as_international'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PhoneNumberField` has some properties to get in different formats. To show the value as `String` you need to use one of the following:

```
mobile.as_e164
mobile.as_national
mobile.as_international
mobile.as_rfc3966
```

It's recommended to set a default behavior based on the type you want to get on `settings.py`.

Comment: I tried this. But got the AttributeError. print(mobile.as_international)
AttributeError: 'PhoneNumberField' object has no attribute 'as_international'

Comment: I solved it. It was my silly mistake while retrieving current active user with obj = get_user_model(). I was trying to get value directly from the return object of this function. I solved it by doing user_data = obj.objects.get(username=user_name). Now I am able to access the user_data.mobile.as_international value